# Authentication levels and for specific people

Tags: authentication, facebook, authorization, login-control

Is it possible to have login levels with the facebook authentication? Also, is it possible to only give permission to login in my website if you meet certain requirements, like for example being in a facebook group, or liking a page?

I have a students website, and I want them to be able to login using facebook but not every one can access the information only students form my course. So is it possible to check if they are in the course closed group before letting them login?

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that **prior** to the login.  However, immediately after the login you can validate, by their facebook id, if they're on your list of approved people, and redirect away others who are not.  Google for Facebook fan gate examples, there's alot of them out and about.